# Python Faker Datetime Generation returns tuple with datetime in it - instead just datetime

Tags: python, datetime, tuples, comparison

for testing purposes i want to compare two datetime objects.

```
dt1 = fake.date_time() # assumming 2021-03-25 08:56:12
```

[dt1 structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktItt.png)

```
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-03-25 08:56:12', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

[dt2 structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O97qY.png)

The comparision fails as i try to compare a datetime object with a tuple which has a datetime object in it.

If I try to just assign the first element of the tuple (dt1) like so:

```
dt1 = fake.date_time()[0]
```

I get the follow error:

[Error directly assign tuple element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRdN7.png)

But if i do the following, it works:

```
dt1 = fake.date_time()
dt1 = dt1[0]
```

What do I not understand here? :( And why isn't faker directly returning a datetime?

Thank you for any help.

I use python 3.7 and faker 6.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

As I was preparing the whole code to be passed here, I discovered the issue.

I copied this line from a dict definition, and it had the comma at the end...

```
dt = fake.date_time(),
```

Obviously then python creates a tuple, I just didn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) `date_time` function source code you'll see only a single `datetime.datetime` object retuns:

```
def date_time(self, tzinfo=None, end_datetime=None):
    """
    Get a datetime object for a date between January 1, 1970 and now
    :param tzinfo: timezone, instance of datetime.tzinfo subclass
    :example DateTime('2005-08-16 20:39:21')
    :return datetime
    """
    # NOTE: On windows, the lowest value you can get from windows is 86400
    #       on the first day. Known python issue:
    #       https://bugs.python.org/issue30684
    return datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=tzinfo) + \
        timedelta(seconds=self.unix_time(end_datetime=end_datetime))
```

I suspect an unwanted change has been applied to the `dt1` object (or it can be a debugger bug also), as I can see in the error clearly stated that the `datetime.datetime` object is not subscriptable . Would you add the complete code for further checking?